# ORA 907: faltan paréntesis derecho. CREATE TABLE AS

Tags: sql, oracle

Buenas, por favor alguien podría ayudarme en esta sentencia? 
Está bien de acuerdo a la estructura pero me sale que faltan los paréntesis derecho. Muchas gracias.

```
CREATE TABLE HIST_CLIN_REPETIDAS_POR_APP 
AS
(
SELECT COUNT(*), 
    NUM_HIST_CLIN,
    AP_PAT,
    AP_MAT,
    PRIMER_NOMBRE,
    COD_APP
from USRCRPWRK.CDI_PERSONA
WHERE NUM_HIST_CLIN <> 0 
GROUP BY NUM_HIST_CLIN ,
    AP_PAT,
    AP_MAT,
    PRIMER_NOMBRE,
    COD_APP
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COD_APP, count(*) desc
)
```

Comment: El order no tendria sentido, la tabla creada en realidad no tiene "orden" (el orden se da al hacer el select). Mas alla de eso, parece todo bien.. a simple vista...

Comment: Veo que debido al mensaje de error, se está asumiendo de que se trata de un simple error tipográfico, y por eso veo votos para cerrar. Pero en realidad no es el caso aquí. Si toman la pena de examinar bien la pregunta y respuesta, verán que OP no cometió un error tipográfico. Es Oracle que no está lanzando un error claro, y el tener esta pregunta/respuesta definitivamente puede ayudar a otros que también no entiendan la razón de este error.

Answer (score 2):

Este es uno de esos casos dónde Oracle te lanza un mensaje de error imposible de entender.

Contrario a lo que dice el error, el problema es que no le gusta la presencia de la claúsula `ORDER BY` en el subquery. En efecto, en algunos tipos de subqueries, Oracle no permite la claúsula `ORDER BY`, y este es uno de esos casos.

Puedes solucionar el error de 2 maneras:

1. Quitar la claúsula `ORDER BY`:

   En realidad, siendo que estás creando una tabla, y por definición, una tabla no mantiene los registros en orden, probablemente el `ORDER BY` está de más de todas maneras y no te ayuda mucho.
2. Quitar las paréntesis:

   Si de verdad necesitas el `ORDER BY` para optimizar el orden físico de los registros al momento de crear la tabla, se puede hacer. Aunque parezca raro, es solo cuestión de modificar la sintaxis para no usar paréntesis. O sea, en vez de:

   ```
   create table HIST_CLIN_REPETIDAS_POR_APP as (select ... order by ...)
   ```

   ...puedes hacer:

   ```
   create table HIST_CLIN_REPETIDAS_POR_APP as select ... order by ...
   ```

   ... y aunque es extraño, de esta forma, Oracle sí acepta la claúsula `ORDER BY`.

---

Una vez que corrijas este error, notarás que vas a recibir otro error diferente. Esto es porque para poder crear una tabla a partir de una consulta, todas las columnas devueltas por la consulta deben tener un nombre asignado. En tu caso, no le va a gustar que estés devolviendo `COUNT(*)` sin asginarle un alias. Vas a tener que corregir eso también:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS escoge_un_alias,
```

Comment: Es verdad, ya había resuelto el problema del Alias.
Y lo de quitar los paréntesis, no lo había deducido. 
Muchísimas gracias.